# Linearising plane autonomous systems of ODEs Unusual Notation in a Differential Equations course for Taylor Expansion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading my notes and am having trouble with what
x|p and y|p means-
Zeta and Eta are functions of t. This is to do with plane autonomous systems of differential equations. I have uploaded the attachment.
Thanks,
[image]

New file:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what is being done is introducing some translated coordinates. This is done so that the critical point $p=(a,b)$ is at the origin of the $(\zeta(t), \eta(t))$ coordinate system, where as it was not at the origin of the $(x(t), y(t))$ coordinate system. This is a useful thing to do!

Then secondarily, a linearization of the variables is made about this critical point $p$. This has just been done using a Taylor series to first order in the two variables; you might have heard this as been described as a tangent plane?

I agree the notation here is a little confusing, but this is essentially what it means:

\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = \dot{\zeta} = X(a+\zeta, b+ \eta) \approx X(a,b) + \zeta \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} (a,b) + \eta \frac{\partial X}{\partial y} (a,b).
\end{equation}

So this is just a first order Taylor series of the function $X$ in the two variables $x,y$, about the point $p = (a,b)$.

I hope this answers your question.

**EDIT:**

Yes, I agree it is silly having derivatives w.r.t $x,y$ when we want an expression as a function of $\zeta, \eta$. It seems like a backwards way to write it. Really, if I saw the expression I would write its Taylor series like

\begin{equation}
X(\zeta + a, \eta + b) \approx X(a,b) + \zeta \frac{\partial X}{\partial \zeta} (a,b) + \eta \frac{\partial X}{\partial \eta} (a,b).
\end{equation}

But we can see these two forms of the derivatives are equivalent using the chain rule;
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial \zeta} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x} \frac{d x}{d \zeta} = \frac{\partial X}{\partial x},
\end{equation}

and similarly for the derivatives w.r.t $y, \eta$.

Comment: I've added another picture- why is the partial differentiation with respect to x and y though- don't we want variables to be zeta and eta so differentiate with respect to them?

Comment: @Arcane1729 I've added to my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: by d(Zeta)/dx I think you meant d(X)/d(zeta)?

Comment: If that's the case then I understand thank you:)

Comment: the partial derivative of dx/d(zeta) is 0 because zeta is a function of time only?

Comment: no, $x = \zeta + a$, so $dx/d\zeta = 1$. And yes, whoops. Sorry.